# Pack char to bytes in python using struct

Tags: python, struct, unicode, byte

I am trying to pack a char to bytes with python using the struct package but my code won't return 4 bytes when packing the char using this code:

```
def charToHex(s):
#check if string is unicode
if isinstance(s, str):
    print(struct.pack('<c', 'a'.encode(encoding='utf-8')))
    return '{:02x}'.format(struct.unpack('<I', struct.pack('<c', s.encode('utf-8')))[0])

#check if input is already a byte
elif isinstance(s, bytes):
    return '{:02x}'.format(struct.unpack('<I', struct.pack('<c', s))[0])

else:
    raise Exception()
```

Can anyone explain to me why this won't work? I am just trying to convert the unicode char to 4 bytes and unpack it but it won't even pack correct.

Comment: The [`c` format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters) is `char` in the C sense of a single byte, not the Python sense of a Unicode code point. Since the UTF-8 encoding of a Unicode character is anywhere from 1 to 4 bytes, you can't `pack` it as a `c`. You'd have to do something silly like pad it out to 4 bytes and pack that as `4c` (at which point it's a lot simpler to use UTF-32 instead of UTF-8).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`c` format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters) is `char` in the C sense of a single byte, not the Python sense of a Unicode code point.

Meanwhile, the whole point of UTF-8 is that it's variable width. A character may encode to anything from 1 to 4 bytes. So you can't pack that into a `c`. You could pad it out to 4 bytes and then pack it into a `4c` or an `I` or something, but that's a pretty silly thing to do.

If you want to use exactly 4 bytes for each character, much simpler to just use UTF-32. Or, since the UTF-32 encoding of a single character is just the Unicode code point as a 4-byte int, and that's exactly the same thing that `ord` returns, you can just skip the `encode` step.

For a single-char `bytes`, it *does* make sense to pack as a `c`—but then it makes no sense to unpack that as an `i`.

In fact, it's not clear what you're even using `struct` for here. If all you're trying to do is `pack` a number and `unpack` the same number, just use the number as-is.

Meanwhile, `02x` doesn't make much sense as a format for a 4-byte integer, because a 4-byte integer takes 8 hex digits, not 2.

So, what you probably wanted was something like this:

```
def charToHex(s):
    #check if string is unicode
    if isinstance(s, str):
        return format(ord(s), '08x')
    #check if input is already a byte
    elif isinstance(s, bytes):
        return format(ord(s), '02x')
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I did the 02x because I wanted the output to be two hex numbers instead of the whole thing as it is because I want it to return only two hex numbers.

Comment: @Silver So what two hex digits do you want to return for a non-ASCII character like `ł` whose code point is 3 or more digits long in hex?

Comment: Aaah I get your point but the program won't take non-ASCII characters as an input and I have to stick to the requirements for this program.

Comment: @Silver In that case, you could `s = s.encode(‘ascii')` if given a `str`, and then only deal with the `bytes` case. (If someone does pass you a non-ASCII character somehow, you’ll get an exception from the encode.) But you can just use `02x` as you say. In that case if you get non-ASCII characters somehow, you’ll end up returning 3 or 4 or 7 digits instead of 2 and probably screwing up your output instead of raising an exception. Which wouldn’t be great for a production web server, but for homework that didn’t even mention non ASCII characters, yeah, I’ll bet it’s fine.